# Crear metadatos desde Windows form con c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Alguien me puede asesorar acerca de como crear el metadatos de un aplicación desde windows form con c#?

Básicamente lo que necesito es crear las tablas y procedimientos de mi aplicación en la base de dato se seleccionada en el inicio de sesión de mi aplicación.

Anteriormente estaba trabajando con delphi 7 y Borland como IDE y ahí utilizo un componente gráfico llamado scripter el cual me permite ejecutar desde procedimientos hasta crear procedimientos y tablas. En esta ocasión  necesito hacer los mismo pero no encuentro un componente que me ayude realizar esto.

Comment: Que es lo que queres crear?

Comment: Dos procedimientos y 6 tablas

Comment: en una base de datos? desde dentro de tu programa o la IDE?

Comment: En una base de datos, Al inicio de mi aplicación me muestra las instancias de servidores después de seleccionar uno te pide el usuario y la contraseña de ese servidor con eso con esos datos creo la cada de conexión que almaceno el regedit, después de eso tomo esa cadena de conexión y se la ingreso el scripter para crear las tablas en el base de datos. Pero mi duda es que componente utilizo para crear las tablas directamente en slq server en c#

Comment: Ah necesitas un componente particular para c#, como el que tenes en delphi. Desconozco si existe algo asi, y esta pregunta se acerca mucho a ser basada en opiniones :(

Comment: si o alguna forma de crear las tablas de desde c#

Comment: Las tablas se crean con un create table (dependiendo de tu db la sentencia puede variar). Eso se hace directamente desde el programa a tu db.

Comment: si esto es lo que introduzco en el scripter ejemplo: create table Usuarios( idUsuario int not null primary key identtiy(1,1), nombre varchar(50), apellidos varchar(100), etc. );

Comment: Entonces solo debes crear la conexion y ejecutar el mismo query que ejecutabas en ese scripter...